# expect script giving error

Tags: shell-script, scripting, expect

on the remote machine there is one script `./bin/show_info.py` which I want to execute and get the output on the local machine, for which i have created a script with expect.

If I run the below command it works properly, but when the same in mentioned in the script it gives error.

```
ssh IPaddress "./bin/show_info.py |  grep  total -A2 | grep -v ^+ | grep -v ^-  | sed 's/total.*//g'" > Report_2017.txt
```

**script error**

```
[root@centseven ~]# ./directconnect
spawn echo -e > Report_2017.txt
extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn sh -c "ssh IPaddress "./bin/show_info.py | grep total -A2 | grep -v ^+ | grep -v ^- | sed 's/total.*//g'" > Report_2017.tx..."
    (file "./directconnect" line 6)
```

**file content**

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout 5

spawn echo -e > Report_2017.txt

spawn sh -c "ssh IPaddress "./bin/show_info.py | grep total -A2 | grep -v ^+ | grep -v ^- | sed 's/total.*//g'" > Report_2017.txt"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Password:"
send "54321\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes are a problem in your case in the `expect` script.

```
spawn sh -c "ssh IPaddress "./bin/show_info.py |.. sed 's/total.*//g'" > Report_2017.txt"
```

Just observe that due to the double quotes ending after IPaddress, the pipe is left exposed.

You may want to try this:

```
spawn sh -c "ssh IPaddress \"./bin/show_info.py |.. sed 's/total.*//g'\" > Report_2017.txt"
```